# Writing a Windows Media Center Plugin with C++

Tags: c++, sdk, windows-media-center

I have been searching for a way to create a windows media center plugin with C++, does anyone know if this is possible (with current available tools)? I have the SDK for C#, but would really rather stick to C++ if it all possible.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always use C++/CLI, either for the whole thing or just to create a thin shim between Media Center and your unmanaged C++.

C++/CLI is rarely used but it is fantastic for creating a bridge between the managed and unmanaged worlds. It's much better than the old Managed C++, if the thought of that has put you off checking it out.